# How do we know F(x,y)=c level sets constrained by function G(x,y) = z will intersect when finding Lagrange Multipliers?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I am struggling with Lagrange Multipliers proof.  I am OK once I accept the fact that the constraint overlaps somewhere. Usually the proofs will say f(x,y)= c and g(x,y) = c.  How do we know the level sets overlap somewhere ? Can someone explain? Thank you.
P.S. once the overlap is established the rest of the proof almost seems a forgone conclusion if the gradient is perpendicular to the level set at that point.

Comment: They do not have to be the same c.

Comment: I edited the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I mean, f is defined everywhere, so at all points of the level set of g you are on *some* level set of f, though in general which one varies as you move along the level set of g.

Comment: Consider a familiar example: maximizing a linear function subject to lying on some circle. So say $f(x,y)=x+y$ and $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. $g$ is forced to be $1$. Level sets of $f$ intersect with the circle in $0$, $1$, or $2$ points, depending on the value of $c$ that you chose. The fact that they sometimes don't intersect at all is not a problem: those level sets of $f$ are ruled out from the optimization problem altogether.

Comment: Level sets are flat are they not?  Are you not looking from the top down on the function. ?  Is it not the case that the area you look down on top of can be located anywhere?  So how is it that the function you are maximizing must have some level set that will overlap just that one particular restraint that can in principle be located anywhere?  My intuition fails me somewhere.

Comment: Again for intuition consider my simple example. A level set of $g$ is a circle centered at the origin, a level set of $f$ is a line with slope $-1$. Neither are a portion of a circle or a portion of a line determined by your "viewfinder". It's true that not every circle and line intersect, but every circle certainly has *some* lines that intersect it, because lines fill out the entire plane.

Comment: ah.  ...and there is the rub for me.  ..certainly there are SOME lines intersecting it but how do we know that once the constraint is given that that particular constraint will "overlap" somewhere so we can use the gradients to find the maximum or minimum point ?

Comment: Only the constraint for $g$ is really held fixed. The relevant level set of $f$ is not given in advance, it is part of the solution to the problem. In my example, I am given $f(x,y)=x+y$ and the constraint $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2=1$, and now I want to find a level set of $f$ which is tangent to the given level set of $g$.

Comment: gotcha ...you have now reduced my question to the exact essence , here it is ...now how do ya know that there will exist at least one level set of that particular f that  will work.  ?  the essence of the Lagrange multiplier proof.

Comment: Assuming your level set of $g$ is not empty, *some* level set of $f$ must intersect it, because the level sets of $f$ fill out the domain of $f$, i.e. in symbols $\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f^{-1}(\{ x \})=\mathrm{Dom}(f)$.

Comment: (Cont.)  In principle it could happen that no level sets are tangent to the level set of $g$; this is analogous to there being no critical point in the unconstrained context. I'm not sure this is possible if the domain is the whole space, but if the domain is a square and $g(x,y)=y$, then it is certainly possible (because this corresponds exactly to a 1D function having its maximum at the endpoint of an interval).

Comment: gotcha ...you've been more than kind ...let me chew on that awhile.